# Pygame, How to make an object follow another object?

Tags: python, pygame

In my game I have two images, the player image and the weapon image. The player object can move with the arrow keys and will always face the mouse. I am looking for a way to position the weapon object relative to the player object object, my current attempt results in the weapon object always being directly below the player instead of being on the 'right side' of the player. It is better illustrated by the attached GIF.[The gif is of what my current implementation looks like.](https://gyazo.com/e6255d963af92548e69e782a41b3acca)

Comment: Please show us your code (a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply blit the weapon image onto the player image, so you only need to rotate one image.

You probably want to keep a copy of the original player image in cause you want to implement more weapons or other features.